# leveling up in skyrim

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, pc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How many skill points does it take to level up?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/34962/how-many-skill-points-does-it-take-to-level-up)

Am I doing something wrong, or is leveling up in Skyrim just very slow? I'm about to leave the college in Winterhold to find out more info on the Elder Scrolls, but I'm only level 10.

Maybe a better question would be, what all effects leveling up? Does killing enemies gain XP or just when you improve a skill? I die way to often, even in simple fights and I feel like I'm missing something important.

Also, is there a place I can store my extra items that I'm carrying? I'm constantly over 200-250 in my carry weight so I can't get a lot of items when I'm doing other quests.

Comment: For your second question, see http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/35314/where-can-i-safely-store-my-stuff

Comment: that's funny, I thought leveling was too fast in this game and I intentionally modded mine to slow it down :P